# wsgi.py to replace source variables

Tags: python, django, apache2, wsgi

How would I do the following in my `wsgi` file, which is imported by apache on production?

```
$ source env_template.sh 
$ python manage.py runserver
>>> Stage: debugging
Validating models...
```

In my settings file I have stuff like the following, which `source` sets:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY']
```

I would like apache to load all the variables in env_template.sh on starting it. Am I able to do that in the `wsgi.py` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in any sane manner. I recommend that you either restrict the file to simple "key=value" lines and then parse it out, or move the specific values to separate files and then read them out in both scripts.

Comment: Where would it be parsed out? In the wsgi file?

Comment: If you like, but if you do it in `settings` instead then you won't need to load them in the shell at all.